# Является ли предложение СПП определительное?

Tags: спп, синтаксический-разбор

Так вот, командующий просил передать лично вам благодарность за тот подвиг, который вы совершили.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Совершенно верно. Союзное слово *который* в данном случае передает значение определения.